# How to send POST Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am studying Angular 2/4 to be able to use that framework soon, but I am very confused with the POST part, I am using the Github API to post an "issue" in my repository but I still can not do it ... so I would be very Grateful if you can clarify that point to send a "issue" type test to understand how it works in Angular 2/4 since I understand that it has to be sent in format "JSON" to work but I do not understand how ... Using github api: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

My code:

*github.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GithubService {

  private username: string;
  private reponame: string;
  private client_id = '+++++++++++++++++++++++';
  private client_secret = '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Github Service Ready...');
    this.username = 'anubis';
  }

  getGithubUser() {
    return this.http.get('http://api.github.com/users/' + this.username
      + '?client_id=' + this.client_id
      + '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret )
      .map( res => res.json());
  }

  getGithubRepository() {
    return this.http.get('http://api.github.com/users/' + this.username
      + '/repos'
      + '?client_id=' + this.client_id
      + '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret )
      .map( res => res.json());
  }

  // to search another user and show his/her repositories
  SearchAgain(usernamenew: string) {
    this.username = usernamenew;
  }


  // I HAVE PROBLEMS IN THIS PART
  addIssue(forms) {
    this.reponame = 'LinioAngularProfileListMarcoAntonioVMontoyaCardenas';
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    return this.http.post('http://api.github.com/repos/ ' + this.username + ' / '
        + this.reponame + ' /issues?' + forms
      + '?client_id=' + this.client_id
      + '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret,
      {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

*issue.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GithubService } from '../../Services/github.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-issue',
  templateUrl: './issue.component.html'
})
export class IssueComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;
  repo: any[];
  username: string;

  constructor(private service: GithubService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = false;

    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          // this.id = +params['id'];
          // this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
          // this.initForm();
        }
      );
  }

  OnSearchUser() {
    // get user information
    this.service.getGithubUser().subscribe(userGit => {
      console.log(userGit);
      this.user = userGit;
    });

    // get user repositories
    this.service.getGithubRepository().subscribe(userRepo => {
      console.log(userRepo);
      this.repo = userRepo;
    });

    this.service.SearchAgain(this.username);
  }

  addIssue( title: string,
            body: string,
            assignee: string,
            milestone: number,
            labels: string) {

    var newIssueAdd = {
      // title: title,
      // body: body,
      // assignee: assignee,
      // milestone: milestone,
      // labels: labels
      title: 'test1',
      body: 'ksjdlkafjslkdf',
      assignee: 'sdljflksjadflñdks',
      milestone: 1,
      labels: 'testlbl'
    };

    console.log(newIssueAdd);

    this.service.addIssue(newIssueAdd).subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
   }
}
```

*issue.component.html* I'm only using a simple button to send the "issue" without any forms, I tried to make the post worked but I can't...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="well-lg">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Username..."
               [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" (keyup)="OnSearchUser()">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="user">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">{{user.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="{{user.avatar_url}}" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
          <a href="{{user.html_url}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-block">View Profile</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="stats">
            <span class="label label-default">{{user.public_repos}} Public Repositories</span>
            <span class="label label-primary">{{user.public_gists}} Public Github Gists</span>
            <span class="label label-success">{{user.followers}} Followers</span>
            <span class="label label-info">{{user.following}} Following</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group item"><strong>Username: </strong>{{user.login}}</li>
            <li class="list-group item"><strong>Location: </strong>{{user.location}}</li>
            <li class="list-group item"><strong>Email: </strong>{{user.email}}</li>
            <li class="list-group item"><strong>Blog: </strong>{{user.blog}}</li>
            <li class="list-group item"><strong>Member Since: </strong>{{user.created_at}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">User Repositories</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div *ngFor="let re of repo">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <h4><a target="_blank" href="{{re.html_url}}">{{re.name}}</a></h4>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addIssue()">Create Issue</button>
              <p>{{re.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <span class="label label-default">{{re.watchers}} Watchers</span>
              <span class="label label-default">{{re.forks}} Forks</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stick to the definition of the HTTP post method. The request parameters should be passed as 2nd argument in JSON format

Answer (score 0):

In your addIssue method, what type is forms supposed to be? It looks like it's being put into the URL, when it should probably be passed in as the body argument referenced in the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#post-anchor):

> post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable